# i cannot get my add function to be called in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
 var customerDb = {};
    var id_inc = 0;

    exports.listCustomers = function () {
        return customerDb;
    };

    exports.addCustomer = function (customer) {
        id_inc = id_inc + 1;
        customer.id = id_inc;
        customerDb[customer.id] = customer;
    };


    exports.getCustomerById = function (id) {
        return customerDb[id];
    };

    exports.deleteCustomer = function (id) {
        customerDb[id].remove();
    };

    exports.updateCustomer = function (customer) {
        customerDb[customer.id] = customer;
    }
```

Above is my js file that i am using as a database, it has an array for holding the data and also functions for interacting with the data.

```
var util = require('util')
db = ('./../db.js');

exports.index = function (req, res)
{
    res.render('customer/index',
        {
        title:"Customer List",
        customers: db.listCustomers
    })
}

exports.create = function (req, res)
{
    res.render('customer/create')
}

exports.createCustomer = function (req, res)
{

    db.addCustomer(
        {name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, telephone: req.body.telephone}
    );

    res.redirect('/customer');
}
```

This is my route JS file which i am using to call certain functions depending on the page being requested. When the createCustomer route is called, the addCustomer function which is meant to run returns the error "TypeError: db.addCustomer is not a function". below is my jade form for submitting the data to the route.

```
doctype
html
    head
        title Add new customer
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/styles/style.css')
    body
        h3 Customer Details
        form(id='form', method='post', action='/customer/create', enctype='multipart/form-data')
            label(for='Name') Name
            input(type='text', id='name', name='name')
            label(for='email') Email
            input(type='email', id='email', name='email')
            label(for='telephone') Telephone
            input(type='tel', id='telephone', name='telephone')
            input(type='submit', value='Add Customer')
```

Also my listCustomers function doesn't seem to work, i have an each function in my jade template to iterate through the results and display them, "each item in customers" , but it returns an error of "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" .

```
table(class='gridtable')
    tr
        th Id
        th Name
        th Email
        th Telephone
        th Edit
        th Delete
    each item in customers.length ? customers : ['There are no customers']
        tr
            td
                a(href='/customer/details/#{item.id}') #{item.id}
            td #{item.name}
            td #{item.email}
            td #{item.telephone}
            td
                a(href='/customer/edit/#{item.id}') Edit
            td
                a(href='/customer/delete/#{item.id}') Delete
```

Comment: It may be possible that you have failed to properly declare the `db` variable in the second code block. You need to add a comma after `var util = require('util')` since you declare the `db = ('./../db.js')` variable right after it. Give that a try

Comment: i tried that, it still gives me the same error

Comment: Are you sure `db = ('./../db.js');` points to the proper file? Does `db.listCustomers` on the index function work?

Comment: `db.addCustomer` is a valid function, so I assume it is a file linking issue (see comment above)

Comment: pls check the edit i added. The listCustomers function is also not working but i'm not sure where that problem comes from

Comment: Are you able to access the `exports.create = function....`?

Comment: i am sure it points to the proper file. the file is in my root directory. while the customer.js file which is callling it is in my routes folder

Comment: yes, i can access exports.create

Comment: Insert `console.log(db)` in your second code block and post what it returns.

Comment: all i get is the same directory path i already put for db

Comment: Can't believe I missed it. Change `db = ('./../db.js');` to `db = require('./../db.js');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is missing from your database module:

```
db = ('./../db.js');
```

Include the `require`:

```
db = require('./../db.js');
```

Now your DB module is available for use.

As for your second issue (`listCustomers` function doesn't seem to work), I don't know how you are returning the `customerDb` to the DOM. More code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

create class for your db like this and use callbacks instead:

`db.js`:

```
var Db = {
    id_inc: 0,
    customerDb: {},

    listCustomers: function (callback) {
        callback(this.customerDb);
    },

    addCustomer: function (customer, callback) {
        this.id_inc++;
        customer.id = this.id_inc;
        this.customerDb[customer.id] = customer;
        callback();
    },


    getCustomerById: function (id, callback) {
        callback(this.customerDb[id]);
    },

    deleteCustomer: function (id) {
        this.customerDb[id].remove();
        return;
    },

    updateCustomer: function (customer) {
        this.customerDb[customer.id] = customer;
        return;
    }
};

module.exports = Db;
```

and your `controller.js`:

```
var util = require('util');
var db = require('/path/to/db.js');

exports.index = function (req, res)
{
    db.listCustomers(function(customers) {
      res.render('customer/index',
        {
        title:"Customer List",
        customers: customers
      })
    })
}

exports.create = function (req, res)
{
    res.render('/customer/create')
}

exports.createCustomer = function (req, res)
{
    db.addCustomer({name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, telephone, req.body.telephone}, function() {
         res.redirect('/customer');
     });
}
```

and One more thing: you're using `POST` request in express so you'll be need `bodyparser` module for that.. install it as well.

I hope this will help!

Cheers,